# Can I change the name of the main-Activity or not?

Tags: android, android-layout

Does the name of Layout-Definition for view of the main-Activity always have to be main or can I change it?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can change the name of `MainActivity` class in android. But also change it's name in `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

You can also change the layout name from `main.xml` to `*.xml`. Whatever you want. It depends on how to name your files in a project.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can change the name of MainActivity by, opening the directory of the java file in android studio, right-click on it and find refactor, then rename, put in the name you like then click on refactor.

Answer (score 1):

you can change it as you want. by default it will be main.xml and you can change it in any way as you like.
also you change it activity setcontentview(R.layout.newname);

Answer (score 1):

You can change it, but in both xml name and `R.layout.*` (`setContentView`)

Answer (score 1):

Just use the refactor(shift+f6) so easily change the name. And check debugging if it did well.

Answer (score 0):

Rename an Android Activity as follows:
Right-click the .java file and Refactor Rename.
then
verify the AndroidManifest.xml to make sure has the new name.